# Properties of Yoneda embedding for abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'd like to know if certain properties regarding preservation and reflection of (co)limits hold for the functor $w$ defined below. The question is a bit long, but you can just take a look at the definitions, and skip to the question; the preliminary facts are there to justify the claims and to understand where eventual errors could come from. Thank you.

Definitions:

- a short sequence in an abelian category $\sf A$ is a diagram of shape $0\to a'\to a\to a''\to 0$, such that the composition of the central morphisms is $0$;
- let $w:\mathsf A\to [\mathsf A^{op}, \mathsf{Ab}]$ be the functor defined by $a\mapsto \mathsf A(-,a)$;
- let $u:\sf Ab\to Set$ be the forgetful functor, and define the functor $v: [\mathsf A^{op}, \mathsf{Ab}]\to [\mathsf A^{op}, \mathsf{Set}]$ by $v(h)=uh$;
- set $y:=vw$ the Yoneda embedding.

Preliminary facts:

(A) $y$ preserves and reflects limits.

(B) Take three functors $f,g,l$ such that $fg=l$. If $l$ and $f$ preserve and reflect a certain class of (co)limits,  $g$ preserves and reflects it too.

(C) Let $\sf C$, $\sf D$ be any two categories. Viewing the class $\operatorname{ob}(\mathsf C)$ as a discrete category, let $i$ be the canonical functor $\operatorname{ob}(\mathsf C)\to \mathsf C$. Define the functor $r:[\mathsf C,\mathsf D]\to[\operatorname{ob}(\mathsf C),\mathsf D]$ by $r(h)=hi$. Now, $r$ preserves and reflects limits and colimits.

(D) The fact that $u$ preserves and reflects limits, together with (C), shows that $v$ preserves and reflects limits.

(E) From now on assume that $\sf D$ is abelian. Also $[\mathsf C,\mathsf D]$ is abelian, and a short sequence $0\to h'\to h\to h''\to 0$ in $[\mathsf C,\mathsf D]$ is exact iff the short sequences $0\to h'(c)\to h(c)\to h''(c)\to 0$ in $\sf D$  are exact for all $c$ in $\sf C$, applying (C).

(F) A short sequence in $\mathsf D$, say$0\to d'\to d\to d''\to 0$, is exact iff the following short sequence in $\sf Ab$ is exact for all $b\in \sf D$: $$0\to\mathsf D(b,d')\to\mathsf D(b,d)\to\mathsf D(b,d'')\to 0.$$

*Question*. Are the italic sentences below true?

(1) $w$ is additive, so preserves finite coproducts, and it preserves short exact sequences by (E) and (F). In particular it preserves cokernels, so *$w$ preserves finite colimits*.

(2) *$w$ preserves and reflects limits* by (A), (B) and (D).

(3) for the remaining properties, do you confirm that *$w$ doesn't reflect colimits and $y$ doesn't even preserve them*? (I know that the Yoneda embedding doesn't preserve colimits in general, but here we are assuming that $\sf A$ is abelian). I have not found counterexamples but it seems very reasonable that these properties are not satisfied.

**Correction after the answers**. (F) is false, only the "if" part holds (that's why I was confused about preservation of cokernels).

Comment: Any conservative functor reflects any colimits it preserves. Of course, this becomes vacuous if the functor does not preserve colimits. In the case of the additive Yoneda embedding, it preserves (and reflects) finitary coproducts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off with, let us recall that limits and colimits in a presheaf-of-abelian-groups category $[\mathsf{C}, \mathsf{Ab}]$ are computed "pointwise", i.e. for a natural transformation $\alpha : F \to G$, $\ker(\alpha) \simeq (a \mapsto \ker(\alpha_a))$, $\operatorname{cok}(\alpha) \simeq (a \mapsto \operatorname{cok}(\alpha_a))$, etc.  Therefore, to ask whether $w$ preserves cokernels is equivalent to asking whether for each object $a$ of $C$, we have that $\mathsf{C}(a, {-})$ preserves cokernels (since we have a canonical comparison morphism of functors anyway of which we are asking whether it is an isomorphism, and a morphism of functors is an isomorphism if and only if it is pointwise an isomorphism).

With this in mind, let us go through the questions:

(1) $w$ preserves cokernels if and only if every object of $\mathsf{A}$ is projective -- which for example is true for the category of vector spaces over a field, but not true for $\mathsf{A} = \mathsf{Ab}$.

(2) $w$ indeed preserves and reflects limits.

(3) $w$ preserves a coproduct $\bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i$ if and only if for each object $a$ of $\mathsf{A}$, the comparison morphism $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathsf{A}(a, A_i) \to \mathsf{A}\left( a, \bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i \right)$ is an isomorphism.  However, considering the case $a = \bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i$ and the identity morphism on the right, this would imply that the identity morphism is a finite sum of morphisms of the form $\iota_i \circ \varphi$ where $\varphi \in \mathsf{A}\left( \bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i, A_i \right)$ and $\iota_i \in \mathsf{A}\left( A_i, \bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i \right)$ is the canonical inclusion.  That implies that $A_j$ is a zero object for any $j$ not in the finite set of indices $i$.  On the other hand, if this condition holds, then $w$ is equivalent to a finite coproduct, which is preserved by the additive functor $w$.  To summarize, we see that $w$ preserves a coproduct $\bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i$ if and only if all but finitely many $A_i$ are zero objects.

Incidentally, there is no reason to expect that $y$ preserves even finite coproducts.  Since similarly to the above, coproducts in a presheaf category $[\mathsf{C}, \mathsf{Set}]$ are computed pointwise, $y$ preserves a finite coproduct $b \oplus c$ if and only if for every object $a$, every morphism in $\mathsf{A}(a, b \oplus c)$ is induced either by a morphism in $\mathsf{A}(a, b)$ or by a morphism in $\mathsf{A}(a, c)$, but not by both.  The last condition is ridiculous for the case of the zero morphism of $\mathsf{A}(a, b \oplus c)$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $w$ preserves the cokernel of a particular morphism $f \in \mathsf{C}(b, c)$ if and only if that cokernel is a *split* epimorphism.  Or, that should be equivalent to the image of $f$ being a direct summand of $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice example. Just two question: (1) to prove the claim  in your comment is sufficient to show that, given an epic $f$ in $\sf A$, $w(f)$ is epic iff $f$ splits? (Since $w$ is already left exact). (2) Does your last paragraph proves that, for any object $a$ in an abelian category $\sf A$, the functor $\mathsf A(a,-):\sf A\to Set$ *never* preserves any coproduct? It is a quite strong property (more than Yoneda not preserving coproducts), but your argument really seems to prove it.

Comment: (1) I believe so,  For any morphism $g$ in $\mathsf{A}$, the cokernel of $g$ is the same as the cokernel of $\ker(g)$, and $w$ preserves this kernel; so we may assume $g$ is monic.  Then, since $0 \to \operatorname{dom}(g) \to \operatorname{codom}(g) \to \operatorname{coker}(g) \to 0$ is exact and $w$ is left exact, $0 \to w(\operatorname{dom}(g)) \to w(\operatorname{codom}(g)) \to w(\operatorname{coker}(g))$ is exact, so $w$ preserves the cokernel if and only if the last arrow is epic.

Comment: (2) Yes, this shows that the only finite coproduct preserved by $y$ is a trivial coproduct of one object.  (And similarly, $y$ does not preserve the initial object.)

Comment: Sorry to comment again this question, but do you confirm that $w$ (doesn't preserve but) reflects finite colimits? Since it reflects finite coproducts (as in Zhen Lin's comment) and reflects cokernels (as it reflects exactness by (F), which is proposition 1.6.11 in Weibel's AITAH). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

(1) $w$ is additive and left exact, meaning that it preserves finite coproducts and kernels. However, it does not preserve cokernels in general, as demonstrated by the counterexample provided. Thus, $w$ does not preserve finite colimits in general.

(2) $w$ preserves and reflects limits, as shown by (A), (B), and (D).

(3) $w$ does not reflect colimits in general. $y$ does not preserve colimits in general, as stated earlier, even when $A$ is abelian. The counterexample [The answer of Daniel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4670853/299848) provided for $w$ not preserving colimits can also be used to show that $y$ does not preserve colimits in the given context.

Comment: Note that the references to my answer are for a totally different previous revision of that answer, which I completely reworked because the previous revision was answering a totally different question from the one the OP asked.